# Self signed root CA works in Safari Mobile but not in app

Tags: ios, ssl

I'm trying to set up a secure dev environment on my Mac.
I've defined a dummy domain in /etc/hosts.
I've installed the following self generated root CA on the simulator:

**Issued To**

Common Name (CN)    ****.com
Organization (O)    ****
Organizational Unit (OU)

**Issued by**

Common Name (CN)    ****.com
Organization (O)    ****
Organizational Unit (OU)

**Validity Period**

Issued On   Wednesday, November 8, 2023 at 9:02:43 AM
Expires On  Saturday, November 5, 2033 at 9:02:43 AM

**SHA 256 Fingerprints**

Certificate f2ed...62f7
Public Key  abcf...4773

I've installed it by downloading the cert (.pem) file, installing it and then going to settings|general|about... to enable it. Just like Apple suggests.

It works fine on Safari Mobile. However, when I try the same from my app I get:

```
2023-11-19 10:42:03.825404+0200 TestApp[22919:2996532] ATS failed system trust
2023-11-19 10:42:03.825475+0200 TestApp[22919:2996532] Connection 1: system TLS Trust evaluation failed(-9802)
2023-11-19 10:42:03.825559+0200 TestApp[22919:2996532] Connection 1: TLS Trust encountered error 3:-9802
2023-11-19 10:42:03.825612+0200 TestApp[22919:2996532] Connection 1: encountered error(3:-9802)
2023-11-19 10:42:03.826104+0200 TestApp[22919:2996532] Task <B0C44DAC-4B59-44D5-891C-5B8BE21C3938>.<1> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: -1200 [3:-9802])
2023-11-19 10:42:03.829664+0200 TestApp[22919:2996532] Task <B0C44DAC-4B59-44D5-891C-5B8BE21C3938>.<1> finished with error [-1200] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, NSErrorPeerCertificateChainKey=(
    "<cert(0x131811800) s: ****.com i: ****.com>"
), NSErrorClientCertificateStateKey=0, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://****.com/, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://****.com/, NSUnderlyingError=0x6000030481e0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerTrust=<SecTrustRef: 0x600000f240a0>, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9802, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9802, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerCertificates=(
    "<cert(0x131811800) s: ****.com i: ****.com>"
)}}, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <B0C44DAC-4B59-44D5-891C-5B8BE21C3938>.<1>"
), _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9802, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <B0C44DAC-4B59-44D5-891C-5B8BE21C3938>.<1>, NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=<SecTrustRef: 0x600000f240a0>, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.}
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, NSErrorPeerCertificateChainKey=(
    "<cert(0x131811800) s: ****.com i: ****.com>"
), NSErrorClientCertificateStateKey=0, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://****.com/, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://****.com/, NSUnderlyingError=0x6000030481e0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerTrust=<SecTrustRef: 0x600000f240a0>, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9802, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9802, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerCertificates=(
    "<cert(0x131811800) s: ****.com i: ****.com>"
)}}, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <B0C44DAC-4B59-44D5-891C-5B8BE21C3938>.<1>"
), _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9802, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <B0C44DAC-4B59-44D5-891C-5B8BE21C3938>.<1>, NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=<SecTrustRef: 0x600000f240a0>, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.}
```

I've considered the info.plist and disabled NSAllowsArbitraryLoads.
I've also tried the same request with a standard domain (e.g. google) and it works fine with no errors.